# Is it possible to place a grid in Nokia maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Im using nokia maps javascript api, is posible place a grid in the map?

Comment: define `grid`....could be interpreted as html table overlay or coordinate related grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a transparent grid PNG as an overlay.

First create a 256x256 PNG file as  shown below.

[image: Grid.PNG]

Then use that as your `getTileUrl()`  function, so it is returned over all of the Map tiles on the map.

```
var getTileUrl = function (zoom, row, column) {            
       return "https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ncK.png";
};
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

An example can be seen below, with your own PNG file, [app id and token](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token) of course .

```js
    /*  Set authentication token and appid 
    *
    *   please register on http://api.developer.nokia.com/ 
    *   and obtain your own developer's API key 
    */
    nokia.Settings.set("appId", "MY APP ID"); 
    nokia.Settings.set("authenticationToken", "MY TOKEN");
        
        // Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
        // Create a map inside the map container DOM node
        var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
         // initial center and zoom level of the map
         center: [52.515, 13.405],
         zoomLevel: 14,
         components: [
          // ZoomBar provides a UI to zoom the map in & out
          new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), 
          // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
          new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
         ]
        });
        var getTileUrl = function (zoom, row, column) {
        
          return "https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ncK.png";
         };
        
         tileProviderOptions = {
          getUrl: getTileUrl, // Obligatory function
          max:20, // The highest zoom level for the overlay.
          min:1, // The lowest zoom level for the overlay.
          opacity: 0.5, // Overlay opacity.0 is fully transparent, 1 is fully opaque.
          alpha:true // This value tells the renderer to read the alpha channel; required if opacity is used.
         },
         // Create an overlay by calling the constructor for ImgTileProvider
         gridOverlay = new nokia.maps.map.provider.ImgTileProvider(tileProviderOptions);
         
        // Add the overlay to the map
        map.overlays.add(gridOverlay);
```

```css
html {
            overflow:hidden;
           }
           
           body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
           }
           
           #mapContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
           }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=EmulateIE10;"/>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
          <title>Nokia Maps Example: Adding an overlay to the map</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
          <style type="text/css">
           
          </style>
         </head>
         <body>
          <div id="mapContainer"></div>
          <div id="uiContainer"></div>

         </body>
        </html>
```