# Nokia HERE Maps canvas drawing speed

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, here-api

I'm trying to draw a grid of rectangles on top of the map tiles using the Javascript API and highlight (switch `fillColor` for) whichever rectangle is currently under the mouse pointer. I would expect such a small change to be effective almost immediately.

However the speed at which changes take place is unbearable for something like this, as changes seem to trigger with a delay of maybe 100ms or so. This applies even if I save a reference to one of the rectangles on a 2x2 grid and then change its color from the console. So this seems unlikely (but still possible) to be a performance issue but rather feels like the Maps simply won't refresh often enough.

Is there maybe a way for me to tell the Maps to redraw a region immediately, or should I use some other way of drawing which would be more performant? I currently have a workaround of using a floating div as the highlight, but it feels a bit wrong and comes with other issues to hack around.

```js
rect = new nokia.maps.map.Rectangle(boundingBox, opts)
...
// slow, but not a deal breaker
map.objects.add(rect)
...
// too slow to happen on every mouseenter/mouseleave event
rect.set('fillColor', '000000')
```

I'm using the 2.5 version of the Javascript API and I'm targeting mostly Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `map.update(-1, true);` to force a redraw the map.

Alternatively, one possible performance improvement (which has several caveats) would be to use an overlay for the grid and only one rectangle. This could be of use if you are trying to highlight the current **square** region of a map tile as served from the TMS server.

You could add a 256x256 grid (or 128x128 or 64x64 etc) using the code in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799333/is-it-possible-to-place-a-grid-in-nokia-maps), and then merely move one **rectangle** over the map to show the current highlight:

For a given zoom and coordinate, the current tile `CoordinateZoomToXY` is:

```
var longitude = coord.longitude,
        latitude = coord.latitude,
        tilesPerRow = Math.pow(2, zoom),
        column,
        row;

      longitude /= 360;
      longitude += 0.5;
      latitude = 0.5 - ((Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (latitude * Math.PI / 360))) / Math.PI) / 2.0);

      column = Math.floor(longitude * tilesPerRow);
      row  = Math.floor(latitude * tilesPerRow);
```

hence the reverse operation (`XYZtoCoordinate`) is:

```
var tilesPerRow = Math.pow(2, zoom),
        longitude = column / tilesPerRow * 360.0 - 180.0,
        lat_rad = Math.atan(sinh(Math.PI * (1 - 2 * row / tilesPerRow))),
        latitude = lat_rad * 180.0 / Math.PI;
```

and the current tile is:

```
  nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox.coverAll([
      XYZtoCoordinate(zoom, column , row),
      XYZtoCoordinate(zoom, column + 1, row + 1)]));
```

If you added this to the listener and just moved one rectangle, it **may** help as you would only need to update one map object each time.